# Packet Delay Variation (PDV)

Tags: c++, delay, packet, iocp

I am currently implementing video streaming application where the goal is to utilize as much as possible gigabit ethernet bandwidth

- Application protocol is built over tcp/ip
- Network library is using asynchronous iocp mechanism
- Only streaming over LAN is needed
- No need for packets to go through routers

This simplifies many things. Nevertheless, I am experiencing problems with packet delay variation.

It means that a video frame which should arrive for example every 20 ms (1280 x 720p 50Hz video signal) sometimes arrives delayed by tens of milliseconds. More:

- Average frame rate is kept
- Maximum video frame delay is dependent on network utilization
- The more data on LAN, the higher the maximum video frame delay

For example, when bandwidth usage is 800mbps, PDV is about 45 - 50 ms.

To my questions:

- What are practical boundaries in lowering that value?
- Do you know about measurement report available on internet dealing with this?

I want to know if there is some subtle error in my application (perhaps excessive locking) or if there is no way to make numbers better with current technology.

Comment: please review my edit for readability. Have I kept your meaning intact?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For video streaming, I would recommend using UDP instead of TCP, as it has less overhead and packet confirmation is usually not needed, as the retransmited data would already be obsolete.